# Mandar de manera segura datos de Sqlite a Mysql

Tags: android, android-volley

estoy realizando una sincronización de información que se almacena en la base de datos `Sqlite` mi problema esque es una aplicación de campo es decir se trabajara con datos móviles, pero tengo problema de que no se ejecuten correctamente el envio de información y se pierda la información de sqlite.

> Sincronizar Datos
>   **Este es el primer método que ejecuto para comprobar si hay internet y asi ejecutar EnviarDatos();**

```
private class SincronizarDatos extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        public void onPreExecute() {
            precarga.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       if (isOnline(getApplicationContext())){
            //existe conectividad
            EnviarDatos();
        }else{
            //No existe conectividad.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No existe conectividad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> Envio de Información **Recorremos toda la bdd sqlite y vamos eliminando conforme valla enviando**

```
public void EnviarDatos() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = basededatos.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(basededatos.TABLE_CAJAS, new String[]{"fecha", "rancho", "sector", "trabajador","hora","_id"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("fecha", cursor.getString(0));
                    parameters.put("rancho", cursor.getString(1));
                    parameters.put("sector", cursor.getString(2));
                    parameters.put("trabajador", cursor.getString(3));
                    parameters.put("hora", cursor.getString(4));
                    ProcessRequest(parameters);
                    //Eliminamos la fila ya enviada.
                    basededatos.EliminarDatos(cursor.getString(5));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

> Como ultimo Enviamos Información a Mysql

```
private void ProcessRequest(final Map<String, String> parameters) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_ENVIARDATOS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            //Log.d("Respuesta del servidor",s.toString());
            precarga.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            onPostResume();
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                 //   Toast.makeText(Menu_AgroMovil.this, "Error al enviar datos ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Log.d("Respuesta del servidor",volleyError.getMessage());
                    precarga.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return parameters;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

mi pregunta es como puedo estar verificando el internet o datos móviles para que si no hay acceso o no cuente con MB para enviar, no se ejecute las tareas.
Saludos!

Comment: Solo que en el `doInBackground` no puedes mandar un Toast ya que es la actividad que se esta ejecutando en segundo plano y no puedes interactuar o con el hilo principal, podrias probar quitando el internet al cel y tratar de enviar los datos y veras que dara un error

Answer (score 1):

Una consulta te refieres a que se realice el envio de datos, ¿si y solo si las condiciones de red son adecuadas para la transmision de datos?.

- Una solución seria enviar un checksum o suma de verificación es decir que al transmitir los datos a tu servicio web este te devuelva un código de estado indicándote si se recibieron todos los datos y si se puedo insertar todo en tu base de datos.
- O puedes obtener la intensidad de la señal de tus datos móviles y dependiendo si son adecuados realizar el envió de datos o no:

`TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();`